# JSF 2 + f:ajax + listener not called

Tags: ajax, jsf, trinidad

sample page.

```
<tr:outputText value="#{my.name}" id="name"/>
<tr:commandButton text="Click" action="#{my.doaction}" id="test1">
<f:ajax event="click" listener="#{my.myajax}" render="name"></f:ajax>
</tr:commandButton>
</tr:form>
</ui:define>
</ui:composition>
```

Managed bean...scope request

```
@PostConstruct
public void init(){
    _name = "default";
}

public void doaction(){
    System.out.println("In doaction");
}

public void myajax(AjaxBehaviorEvent ae) throws javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException{
    _name = "Ajax";
}

public void myajax() throws javax.faces.event.AbortProcessingException{
    _name = "Ajax";
}
```

i am using trinidad buttons. jsf 2. my listener is not being called.  none of the myajax(AjaxBehaviorEvent ae)
 myajax() 
are called. however my doaction method is being called.
what am i missing. ?

please help.

note: my facesconfig is below. does specifying 2.2 and using trinidad 2.0 and myfaces 2.0 create this problem?

```
<faces-config
xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_2.xsd"
version="2.2">
<application>
<default-render-kit-id>org.apache.myfaces.trinidad.core</default-render-kit-id>
</application>
</faces-config>
```

Comment: is it *not called*? (set a breakpoint!) or is the value not stored? depending on how trinidads commandbutton works like, it might simple cause a reload after clicking, calling `init()` again, cause your bean is `RequestScoped` and overwritting the name attribute in the second request.

Comment: i did put a breakpoint in both ajax methods.none of them are hit..

Answer (score 0):

You cannot mix an action called in ajax with an action refreshing the page in h:commandButton.

You have to choose.

Did you try like this ?

```
<tr:commandButton text="Click" id="test1">
    <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{my.doaction}" render="name" />
    <f:ajax event="click" listener="#{my.myajax}" render="name" />
</tr:commandButton>
```